# Saving a String to an internal file in Android?

Tags: android, string, file, save

I'm trying to save a String to a file in android. Here is a [link to my code](http://www.utryit.net/c0der18/save_data_to_file.txt) to try and show what I'm doing. (Sorry, I'm still not sure how to properly format code for the question)-

The String contains Accelerometer data values that constantly change. I want to save them to this file so that I can review the values later. I'm only beginning Android Development so if you could help with the code or know a tutorial that is easy to follow. 
Thanks.

Comment: To format code just add mark all code and press CTRL+K ( Windows ) or CMD+k ( Mac OSX ). Or you could add 4 spaces before every line, or you could add a ---> ` <---- at the beginning and a ---> ` <---- at the end. Of course without the arrows. They are just there to point out which symbol you need to use

Comment: You just need to add 4 spaces to turn normal text line into code ;) You could also write every measurement in a new line by adding `\n` at the end. Or, even more properly, by finding out the end-of-line character (may vary): `EOLchar = System.getProperty("line.separator")`.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for getting back so soon! :D Musterknabe, thank you, i will try that the next time i post a qusetion. Aleksander, thank you but osayligan's link provides the walk through basic tutorial I need. Thanks again for getting back so soon!

Comment: Thanks for the replies. It ended up being way less complicated than I thought! Thanks again to all who answered :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save data in Android, you can use SharedPreferences. You don't need to deal with creating files and saving the values you have.

[Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html) is the Link to a tutorial. Take a look, it's pretty easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to save data in Android. They are explained in more detail in the Android documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

- Shared Preferences - store name/value pairs.
- Internal storage - probably good for your logging needs.
- External storage - usually bigger in size but may or may not exist.

You can search for many examples and tutorials.

Here is a simple snippet example for internal storage:

```
File file = new File(getFilesDir(), fileName);
String filePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
os.write(data);
os.close();
```